# Custom Slider with lightbox playback effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this for my first video and it works fine. but when I try and replicate the same coding using other call outs it doesn't work right. I'm basically playing two videos on two different slides but the second slide plays on the first slide. How can I duplicate this to have to separate videos??
Follow the link to see what I mean.http://jsfiddle.net/4fkf34rq/

```
<p><a href="javascript:;" onClick="toggleVideo();">Click here</a></p>
<!-- popup and contents -->
<div id="popupVid" style="position:absolute;left:0px;
 top:87px;width:500px;background-color:#D05F27;height:auto;display:none;z-index:200;">
    <iframe width="500" height="315" 
     src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/T39hYJAwR40?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" 
      allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <br />
    <br />
    <a href="javascript:;" onClick="toggleVideo('hide');">close</a>
</div>
```

```
function toggleVideo(state) {
    // if state == 'hide', hide. Else: show video
    var div = document.getElementById("popupVid");
    var iframe = div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
    div.style.display = state == 'hide' ? 'none' : '';
    func = state == 'hide' ? 'pauseVideo' : 'playVideo';
    iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func + '","args":""}', '*');
}
```